# How do I run a Runnable Jar File without Java JDK?

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I have a JAR file that I needed transferred to a Mac. The .cmd file "opens" it, but says that it needed the Java JDK. Is there any way around this? The file runs perfectly when I double click the JAR file *and* when I run the .cmd file on my PC; but the Mac *does not* have the JDK. I need an answer by Monday [1/12/2015].

Comment: JDK = java **DEVELOPMENT** kit. If you just want to run a jar, you don't need a DEVEL kit, you just need the JRE - java RUNTIME environment.

Comment: It appears that everyone must install the full JDK to run recently created apps, say with JDK 11, since apparently there is no separate JRE for Java 11 - the latest JRE distribution (jre 1.8.0_241) is Java 8. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the JRE, not the JDK (although the JDK will work too as the JRE is a subset of the JDK) to run a JAR file.

That said, if you want your jar file to run without the end user having the JRE installed then you'll need to include the JRE with the jar. You'll want to use a third party program to do this. Something like launch4j which can bundle the JRE with your jar.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/